# How to activate and deactivate a timer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

So i am trying to create a fixed movement for an image, but i can't seem to make it work correctly. The first block is activate by a timer but I don't know how to turn it off and activate another timer to continue the curve.

```
    BMR = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(BallArchR) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    LMR = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(BallArchL) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    -(void)BallArchR{
        if (Ball.center.x < 284){
            Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x + 2.72 , Ball.center.y - 2 );
        }
        if (Ball.center.x >= 284 && Ball.center.x < 488) {
    Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x + 2.72 , Ball.center.y + 2 );
        }
    }

    -(void)BallArchL{
        if (Ball.center.x > 284){
            Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x - 50 , Ball.center.y - 50 );
        }
        if (Ball.center.x <= 284 && Ball.center.x > 80) {
            Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x - 2.72 , Ball.center.y + 2 );
        }
    }
```

This is the code to make the ball move in a curve, and BallArchR is activated when the game starts up. But i can't turn it off and activate BallArchL. Is there another way to make this work?

Comment: so this app uses c#, c++ and objective? what code is the timer using? can you show the timer code?

Comment: Please note I removed the C# and C++ tags and added Objective-C. Please put relevant tags against your questions.

Comment: I added in the timers. BMR activates when the game starts up.

Comment: [BMR invalidate] will cancel a timer. But you're going to need a whole different approach to get what you want. Don't use timers. Use CoreGraphics or UIView animations.

Comment: when(any action or time interval) BMR have to stop,and LMR start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)stopTimer 
{
    if ([_LMR isValid]) 
{
        [_LMR invalidate];
    }
}
```

You can use this for stop timer.

Also for animation you can use

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
//move your view
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

or

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                            animations:^{
                            //move your view
                            }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

i think one timer is enough for this

```
 BMR = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(BallArchR) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)BallArchR
 {
        if (Ball.center.x < 284)
        {
            Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x + 2.72 , Ball.center.y - 2 );
        }
        if (Ball.center.x >= 284 && Ball.center.x < 488) 
        {
            Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x + 2.72 , Ball.center.y + 2 );
        }
        else
        {
             [self BallArchL ];
        }
  }
  -(void)BallArchL
  {
        if (Ball.center.x > 284)
        {
            Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x - 50 , Ball.center.y - 50 );
        }
        if (Ball.center.x <= 284 && Ball.center.x > 80)
        {
            Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x - 2.72 , Ball.center.y + 2 );
        }
        else
        {
            [BMR invalidate];
        }
  }
```

i'm answered this based on what i have  understand,if it not what you want comment here your requirement clearly...;)

Answer (score 1):

When you need to deactivate timer, first check if the timer is valid or not then deactivate by using "invalidate" method.

```
 if ([BMR isValid]) 
{
    [BMR invalidate];
}
```